# ionic-native/http emite erro "NullInjectorError: No provider for HTTP!"

Tags: ionic, typescript, angular

Estou iniciando no *ionic 3.2* com angular, conforme a documentação https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/ instalei no projeto o modulo `@ionic-native/http` com os seguintes comandos via CMD:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
npm install --save @ionic-native/http
```

Então no script `autenticar.ts` (que faz parte de uma página que criei `autenticar.html`) adicionei o `import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';` conforme:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-autenticar',
  templateUrl: 'autenticar.html'
})
export class AutenticarPage {

  @ViewChild('username') username;
  @ViewChild('password') password;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: HTTP) {
    console.log(http)
  }

...
```

Ao recarregar o aplicativo obtive a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> ```
> Runtime Error
> Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)
> [AutenticarPage -> HTTP]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AutenticarPage -> HTTP]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for HTTP!
> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AutenticarPage -> HTTP]:
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AutenticarPage -> HTTP]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for HTTP! at _NullInjector.get
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1376:19) at resolveToken
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1674:24) at tryResolveToken
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1616:16) at StaticInjector.get
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1484:20) at resolveToken
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1674:24) at tryResolveToken
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1616:16) at StaticInjector.get
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1484:20) at resolveNgModuleDep
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11228:25) at NgModuleRef_.get
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12461:16) at resolveDep
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12951:45)
> ```

Então ao ler nesta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47492777/1518921) o autor afirma que é necessário adicionar ao `app.module.ts` isto `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';`, ficou assim:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

....

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],

...
```

No entanto mesmo depois de instalar e adicionar ao app.modules o erro persiste.

Answer (score 3):

Da uma olhada no item 2 do link que você postou da documentação ele fala que tem que adicionar o import aos providers do seu modulo.

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
providers: [
    HTTP
   ]
...
```